# Running CMD code in Visual Studio Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-c++, cmd

How can I use the following CMD codes in Visual Studio Windows Form?

1-) nslookup xxxx.yyy.com | FIND /i "192.168.1.88" > c:\temp\nslookup.txt

2-) reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\SMC\SYLINK\SyLink" /v "CurrentGroup" > C:\Temp\SymantecKontrol.txt

3-) find /i "Laptopimage" C:\temp\SymantecControl.txt >NUL
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto notfound1

> > > > FORM-1 OPEN<<<<<<

goto done

:notfound1

find /c "192.168" C:\temp\nslookup.txt >NUL
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto notfound

> > > > FORM-2 OPEN<<<<<<

goto done
:notfound

> > > > FORM-3 OPEN<<<<<<

Comment: The real question is why aren't you doing these things natively in C#? And why have you also tagged Visual C++, which is quite a different programming language to C#?

Comment: [DNS Lookup in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns?view=net-6.0), and [Registry in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry?view=net-6.0). It is really backwards to do this kind of thing by launching other programs (which find and nslookup, etc. are) rather than writing the code natively to do the exact same thing in C#.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Because he doesn't know C# at all and always develops "copy-paste"wares.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the commands separately you can do the following:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

string commandExample = "echo Hello!";
Process.Start($"cmd.exe /c {commandExample}");
```

or you can run the batch script:

```
Process.Start("script.bat");
Console.ReadLine();//not needed if you are running it under Windows 
Forms template
```

By my knowledge I don't think it's possible to open a form from batch.

Comment: The below command is not working

  ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
             ps.FileName = "cmd.exe";
             ps.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
             ps.Arguments = @"/c nslookup xxx.yyyyy.com | FIND /i "217.169" > C:\temp\nslookup.txt";


But this is successful;

             ps.Arguments = @"/c echo Hello World ";

Comment: @Hakan DAŞTAN if you mean the command for starting the script you can do Process.Start("cmd.exe /c script.bat"); , script.bat has to be in the same directory as the cmd for it to run, but you can specify the full script path.